# C# to VB.net with lambda translation

Tags: c#, vb.net, lambda

I need to translate the following call from C# to VB.net and would like assistance in its translation.

```cs
MyResponse = await Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode).WaitAndRetryAsync(10, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Hit Polly Sending Data!");
}).ExecuteAsync(() => myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, myStringContent));
```

Comment: https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

Comment: `message =>` is `Function(message)`. `i =>` is `Function(i)`. `(result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>` is `Sub(result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) ... End Sub`. `() =>` is `Sub() ... End Sub`.

Comment: You can use http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I'm afraid to point out that Stackoverflow is **not a code-writing service**. It is a Q/A site designed to _advise_ users and _help them_ with questions about their code, rather than write a program for them. However, as @mggSoft pointed out, there are online converters that are designed to do this for you. *I would be careful though* as you may be better off researching how to do the same thing in VB.net rather than trusting the converter to interpret exactly what you're doing and possibly giving you incorrect code.

Comment: @mggSoft the converter won't convert the code. Try it.

Comment: Yes, you're right, you'd have to add a type for the response, for example: 'var'

Comment: @mggSoft var won't work very well in vb.net.

Comment: @Mary you have to add it to the beggining of the c# code displayed on this post ant then apply the conversion to VB.Net. Anyway, the conversion tool is a helper and sometimes the developer has to complete some code gaps that the tool didn't translate.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the community wont just directly translate code for people, especially when tools like http://converter.telerik.com/ exist. But considering I pasted your code there and got something which was not quite right, I will help you out.

You can't translate your code directly; you are missing a `var` before `MyResponse`, or else `MyResponse` is declared previously.

It would also have been helpful for you to include your `using` statements, especially since you use a NuGet package, [Polly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Polly/), well, I *think*.

Right, so the C# imports make the task simpler

```cs
using Polly;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;
```

And make it easier on us! Format your code a little nicer. You gave us a blob which doesn't even fit in one code frame

```cs
MyResponse = await Policy.HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode).WaitAndRetryAsync(10, i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Hit Polly Sending Data!");
}).ExecuteAsync(() => myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, myStringContent));
```

as opposed to this

```cs
var MyResponse = await Policy
    .HandleResult<HttpResponseMessage>(
        message => !message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        10, 
        i => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 
        (result, timeSpan, retryCount, context) => {
            Debug.WriteLine("Hit Polly Sending Data!");
        })
    .ExecuteAsync(
        () => myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, myStringContent));
```

So Telerik will translate that code into this VB

```vb
Dim MyResponse = Await Policy.HandleResult(Of HttpResponseMessage)(Function(message) Not message.IsSuccessStatusCode).WaitAndRetryAsync(10, Function(i) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Function(result, timeSpan, retryCount, context)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Debug.WriteLine("Hit Polly Sending Data!")
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                End Function).ExecuteAsync(Function() myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, myStringContent))
```

Formatted nicely, it is this

```vb
Dim MyResponse = Await Policy.
    HandleResult(Of HttpResponseMessage)(
        Function(message) Not message.IsSuccessStatusCode
    ).
    WaitAndRetryAsync(
        10,
        Function(i) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        Function(result, timeSpan, retryCount, context)
            Debug.WriteLine("Hit Polly Sending Data!")
        End Function
    ).
    ExecuteAsync(
        Function() myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, myStringContent
    ))
```

However, note that there is a warning on the statement `End Function`

> Function '' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.

This is because the translator is not smart enough to select the correct overload of  `WaitAndRetryAsync`. It chose

```cs
public static AsyncRetryPolicy<TResult> WaitAndRetryAsync<TResult>(this PolicyBuilder<TResult> policyBuilder, int retryCount, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Func<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, Context, Task> onRetryAsync);
```

but it should have chosen

```cs
public static AsyncRetryPolicy<TResult> WaitAndRetryAsync<TResult>(this PolicyBuilder<TResult> policyBuilder, int retryCount, Func<int, TimeSpan> sleepDurationProvider, Action<DelegateResult<TResult>, TimeSpan, int, Context> onRetry);
```

which is passed an Action, instead of Func. *I* know that because you call `Debug.WriteLine` which returns nothing. You'd need to modify that manually, which is simple. Here is the final result, I hope...

```vb
Dim MyResponse = Await Policy.
    HandleResult(Of HttpResponseMessage)(
        Function(message) Not message.IsSuccessStatusCode
    ).
    WaitAndRetryAsync(
        10,
        Function(i) TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        Sub(result, timeSpan, retryCount, context)
            Debug.WriteLine("Hit Polly Sending Data!")
        End Sub
    ).
    ExecuteAsync(
        Function() myHttpClient.PostAsync(url, myStringContent
    ))
```